# rails twitter-bootstrap nav_bar color doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to render this: `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"></div>`

This is my attempt: `<div><%= nav_bar :inverse, :static => top %></div>`

Obviously, it doesn't work. How do I render the html above in ruby on rails?

Comment: turns out `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse"><%= nav_bar :static => top %></div>` Not sure if this will trouble later but for now it works

Comment: What did I just read?